# Differentiating w.r.t. the boundary of the expected value

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I need to solve for general and cont. diff. pdf $g(x)$

$$\frac{d}{db} \int_0^b xg(x)dx$$

Standard Leibnitz rule would give me

$$b g(b) + \int_0^b 0 dx$$

the result makes sense - but I'm not sure whether Leibnitz is applicable here.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the formula is wrong! (it lakcs a division by $P(X \le b)= \int_0^b g(x) \; dx$. Can you correct?

Comment: hint: $bg(b)$ (as the formula stands uncorrected)

Comment: Alright, thank you. I guess given your hint that Leibnitz is indeed applicable.

Comment: ¨Just write out the **definition** of the derivative as a limit ...